# Separating a php array into separate Json responses in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have a function that connects to a mysql database and then retrieves an array of information. It then sends it back to the android phone in a Json response. The phone gets the information but stores it all under one variable. How can I separate the information once it has been sent back to the phone as a json variable?

Comment: you mean the variable contains the json string? You need to decode it back to a native data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse the JSON into an object.